# How to disable a insert button for a Tableview Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to make a list so that users can add items to their favorites. I used `uitableviewcelleditingstyleinsert` for my `tableview`. When a user taps an insert button which has a `+` sign, the item will be added to the favorites list. However, I want each item in the favorites list to be unique, so I when a button is tapped, I want it to automatically become grayscale. How could I set this up in my app?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more your problem?

Comment: Simply put, I want my tableview when it enters editing mode, when I click an insert button to the left of each cell, the button will turn into gray or become darkened, meaning it is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely possible, but not the way you're going about it. You need to create your own accessoryView with the plus sign image, use `- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *) button withEvent: (UIEvent *) event` to know when it's been tapped and then change the UITableViewCell's accessory view based on the subsequent change to your data source.

```
//in your cell creation
UIImageView *i = nil;
if(cellAlreadyUsed)
    i = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"your_gray_image"];
else
    i = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"your_green_image"];
cell.accessoryView = i;
[i release];


- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *) button withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
   //handle changing your data source to reflect that cell was used and reload your table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want every item unique apply logic before inserting it to array.
Compare ur array items with the current item, if match with array item break the loop, u can show an alert also, if not add item to the array list.

It will be a tedious task to customize the insert button.

Comment: Isn't there any built in method for making change of insert button?

Comment: In my last project i googled a lot but no luck. So i gone with explained approach.